# Python Pillow resized image (manga) page details are bad compared to the Photoshop

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a manga page that has a resolution of 1360x1920. I want it to reduce to 496x700.

This is a part of the image without resolution reduced.

[image: details]

This is after lowering the resolution to 496x700.

[image: reduced]

This is the Photoshop version after the lowering resolution

[image]

In short, what photoshop does under the hood to get the result I have shown here? When resizing with photoshop you can select resample method to use. Which is NEAREST by default.
I used the same method with Pillow library but still, the result didn't change.

Sample Code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

img = Image.open("788.png")
img = img.resize((496, 700), Image.NEAREST)
img.save("low.png")
```

Comment: Did you try the choices other than NEAREST?

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried all that Pillow library has.

Comment: And they all produced the same result?

Comment: @ScottHunter check my answer down below. Without converting the image to RGB, yes they produced the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution
I just had to change

```
img = Image.open("788.png")
```

to

```
img = Image.open("788.png").convert("RGB")
```